# Add/Remove class of a nav ul li with jQuery by clicking href inside li

Tags: jquery

I have a navigation list setup to show/hide tabs, which is working properly. I am now trying to add/remove the active class of a nav ul li item only when clicking the text of the href. Currently when you click the list item (space around the text and not just the text) the active class displays. So the active class displays without clicking the link and changing the tabs.

I have tried many variations to accomplish this, with no result.

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#tabs li').click(function() {
    //Removes the active class from any <li> elements
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    //Adds it to the current element
    $(this).addClass('active');
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="warranty-nav">
  <ul id="tabs" class="nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#overview">Overview</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#benefits">Plan Benefits</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#works">How It Works</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#terms">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#faqs">Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 $('#tabs a').click(function() {
     //Removes the active class from any <li> elements
    $('#tabs li.active').removeClass('active');
    //Adds it to the current element
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(function(){
    $('#tabs li').click(function() {
    //Removes the active class from any <li> elements
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    //Adds it to the current element
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
  });
```

- Remove the class of siblings

Answer (score 0):

You're code works, you just need to close you function.

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#tabs li').click(function() {
    //Removes the active class from any <li> elements
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    //Adds it to the current element
    $(this).addClass('active');
  })});
</script>
```

Comment: if other li in the page have active class, it will be removed, if the above code is used. check negative flow.

Comment: @rpeki8 if that is all, you could just add a comment to the op question.